# Very long IO wait times

Tags: performance, vmstat

Following scenario has happened twice with different RAID controllers. One was LSI MegaRAID running RAID5, the second was HP Smart Array E200i running RAID1. At first server works smoothly for few years. Then people start complaining about performance. Then it turns out its not just "application problem" because simple disk operations (like ls on a directory with 20-30 files) can take up to 5 seconds. Here is what vmstat reports during a heavy workload:

```
procs -----------memory------------ ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff   cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs   us sy id wa
 1  8   8944 126004     20 1597500    0    0  1666  5935  282  833   10  3  0 86
 1 16   8944 122276     20 1599636    0    0   612  6300  314  615   10  3  0 87
 1 12   8944 123740     20 1599332    0    0   811  5103  188  794    2  2  0 96
 0 19   8944 121916     20 1600808    0    0   150  7299  163  858    1  1  0 97
 0 16   8944 239244     20 1612256    0    0   647  2522  156  798    0  1  0 99
 0  6   8944 215308     20 1643712    0    0  3030  3060  201  956   33  5  0 62
 1 13   8944 186352     20 1672540    0    0   143  6173  166  931   14  8  0 78
 8  2   8944 137368     20 1710432    0    0   111  6425  171  833   48  4  0 48
 1 11   8944 122500     20 1725892    0    0   306  5222  153  746   69  4  0 27
24 13   8944 128444     20 1729680    0    0   380  5210  170 4484   16  6  8 70
 0  4   8944 124956     20 1731228    0    0   389  4933  272  761    4  2  0 93
 0  6   8944 123004     20 1735780    0    0    15  7856  209  682    1  2  7 90
```

So the server is withdrawn from production usage and tested with bonnie++ and monitored with vmstat which gives pretty much the same results. So it would seem that the disks are faulty. However when querying RAID controller it appears that both logical drive and physical disks are ok. Also kernel logs do not contain any message that can suggest a problem with disk operations.

So my question is: how do I debug further this problem? Do i have to replace controller/disks and simply see after which replacement situation got better? Or perhaps some command can be executed and its results studied to pinpoint exact location of the problem?

Comment: what file system are you running? and how full are your partitions? run iotop and see if there is something strange there. Does your raid card have diagnostics, get them...get smart data for you physical drives? any ptoblems?

Comment: dmesg and /var/log anything strange in there? seeing any io time outs? are you running out of physical memory, is your system paging a lot?

Comment: @user37899: SI/SO under swap would be nonzero if there was active use of memory that has been swapped out to disk (if that is what you mean by paging).

Comment: @user37899: apart from what Kyle already wrote, the rest of your suggestions is either covered by explanation above (kernel/raid diagnostics) or simply can't produce long I/O waits (like full partition).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can it be that write-cache was turned off? maybe battery has died and it switched from write-back to write-through?

some cheap hardware raids without battery and with cache by default enable the cache just for reads - can it be that you set it to use write-cache too and the controller 'lost' the settings?

besides - maybe one of the drives is faulty? try looking at raid logs [MegaCli command line tool should help].

Comment: RAID controller indeed was in write-through mode. Using megarc (MegaCli doesn't work on my controller) i switched it back and now IO wait times are small with performance being quite good.

Comment: @Jacek: Is the battery health okay? Using write cache that isn't battery backed can be risky.

Comment: Yes I know it's risky. I'm not just going to switch write policy and consider problem to be solved. Gonna check battery and replace it if its dead.